# A class for animating messages as feedback to the user

Tags: javascript

This class provides animation messages to the user.  Looking for general feedback.

I've posted the library I use as well if you have time to look that over.

```
/***************************************************************************************************
SMessenger - messaging system to provide feedback to the user
*/
    var SMessenger = $A.Class.create({
        Name: 'SMessenger',

        // static constants
        A: {
            DELAYTRANS:           1000,
            DELAY:                2000,
            GRANULARITY:          15,
            GRANULARITY_POSITION: 1,
            OFFSET:               40,
            RADIX:                10,
            UNITS:                'px'
        },

        // holds dome elements
        E: {

            // the dom holds the messages
            dynamic:      '#dynamic'
        },
        init: function () {

            // pull the elements dynamically at init time
            $A.eachChild(this.E.dynamic, function (val) {
                this.E[val.id] = $A.el('#' + val.id);
            }, this);
        },

        // s_ denotes server response
        populateMessage: function (element, type) {
            var period = '';

            // messages from the server will have a period
            // they are denoted by a preceding s_
            if (type.match("s_")) {
                type = type.replace('s_', '');
                period = '.';
            }
            element.innerHTML = this.E['dyn_' + type].innerHTML + period;
        },

        // creates a fading message for the user
        fadingMessage: function (obj) {
            this.populateMessage(obj.response_element[0], obj.state);
            obj.response_element.fade('down', this.A.DELAY);
        },

        // creates a message that fades up and then fades down.
        popMessage : function (obj) {
            var self = this;
            this.populateMessage(obj.response_element, obj.state);
            $A(obj.pane_element).fade('up', this.A.DELAYTRANS, function () {
                $A.setTimeout(function () {
                    $A(obj.pane_element).fade('down', self.A.DELAYTRANS, function () {
                        self.hideInput(false, obj);
                    });
                }, self.A.DELAY);
            });
        },

        // creates a sliding message
        slidingMessage : function (obj) {
            var self = this,
                el = obj.pane_element;
            this.populateMessage(obj.response_element, obj.state);
            el.style.display = 'inline';
            this.hideInput(true, obj);
            $A.peakOut(el, 40, 2000, function () {
                el.style.display = 'none';
                self.hideInput(false, obj);
            });

        },

        // hides or exposes input - enter, button - while the message is being displayed
        hideInput: function (hide, obj) {
            if (hide) {
                if (obj.input_element) {
                    obj.input_element.removeEventListener("keypress", obj.enter);
                }
                obj.cover_element.style.display = 'inline';
            } else {
                if (obj.input_element) {
                    obj.input_element.addEventListener("keypress", obj.enter);
                }
                obj.cover_element.style.display = 'none';
            }
        },

        // resets inputs
        // set the inputs to empty
        // a focus and a blur will trigger event handlers
        resetInput: function (array, checkbox) {
            $A.someIndex(array, function (val) {
                val.value = '';
                val.focus();
                val.blur();
            });
            if (checkbox) {
                checkbox.checked = true;
            }
        }
    }, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks really good! The only bit I don't like is the nested `ifs`, but I'm really nit-picking.

```
       if (hide) {
            if (obj.input_element) {
                obj.input_element.removeEventListener("keypress", obj.enter);
            }
            obj.cover_element.style.display = 'inline';
        } else {
            if (obj.input_element) {
                obj.input_element.addEventListener("keypress", obj.enter);
            }
            obj.cover_element.style.display = 'none';
        }
```

Maybe....

```
obj.cover_element.style.display = hide ? 'inline' : 'none';
if (!obj.input_element) return;

if (hide) {
   obj.input_element.removeEventListener("keypress", obj.enter);
}
else {
   obj.input_element.addEventListener("keypress", obj.enter);
}
```

Putting the return value at the start, instead of protecting both blocks from it being null, makes it slightly more understandable. But I still don't like that section much.

Answer (score 2):

From a once over:

- if `'s_'` denotes a server response, then you ought to have a variable for it;
   `var serverResponsePrefix = 's_';`
- You should choose a consistent string quote, either always ' or ", my suggestion is '
- You could replace `2000` in `$A.peakOut(el, 40, 2000, function ()` with `DELAYTRANS`
- `hideInput` looks unfortunate.., I would go for

  ```
  var actions = {
        hide : { eventFunction : 'removeEventListener', display = 'none'  },
        show : { eventFunction : 'addEventListener'   , display = 'inline'}};
  var action = hide ? actions.hide : actions.show;
  if (obj.input_element) {
    obj.input_element[action.eventFunction]("keypress", obj.enter);
  }
  obj.cover_element.style.display = action.display;
  ```

  Also, when you think about it, `hideInput` is lying about what it does, it either shows or hides, so it should get a better name, or you should split this out into 2 dedicated functions.
- As always, lowerCamelCase is good for you..

Comment: Your `hideInput` is even more obfuscated!